# How to use a blank master page?

Tags: master-page

We have created a blank master page in SP2013 designer and set it as custom and deafult masterpage.

Now, if we open any of the site page then we get the error:technical error.

Comment: What does the ULS log say?

Answer (score 4):

Sharepoint needs some controls that are defined inside the master page or it will **NOT** render your master page.

I suggest to refer to the following project: http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/ to have a template where you can start to work

Answer (score -1):

Check if the .aspx page is added within:
Site Settings -> Master pages